# MVC Json to HTML table

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to pass a serialized json string (serialized using JsonConvert.SerializeObject) into an html table. I would like to call values inside the json string into the table like this: "model.jsonvalue". I am not sure how to make variables out of the json string.

My Json string:

```json
{
  "stats": {
    "global": {
      "cache": {
        "misses": "5"
      },
      "download": {
        "total-downloaded": "500"
      },
      "error": {
        "config-failed": "50",
        "retries": "20"
      },
      "instance": {
        "resets": "2016-06-23 09:45:07"
      },
      "servers": {
        "server-in-config": "1",
        "servers-running": "1",
        "servers-relays": "1"
      }
    },
    "servers": {
      "12345": {
        "uptime": "0d, 18:01:30",
        "retries": "0",
        "download-size": "54664",
        "server-restart": "1",
        "download-time": "1",
        "start-time": "2016-06-23 09:45:07",
        "logic-time": "123",
        "heartbeat": "1",
        "logic-retry": "0"
      },
      "44444": {
        "start-time": "2016-06-23 09:45:07",
        "download-time": "1",
        "logic-time": "123",
        "download-size": "54664",
        "server-restart": "1",
        "logic-retry": "0",
        "uptime": "0d, 18:01:30",
        "heartbeat": "1",
        "retries": "0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my controller I serialized as follow:

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@path);
string jsonoutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
```

...and I have a controller for the values I want to pass to the tables as follow:

```
public class Stats
{
    public Global global { get; set; }
    public List<server> servers { get; set; }
}

public class Global
{
    public Cache cache { get; set; }
    public Download download { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
    public Instance instance { get; set; }
    public servers servers { get; set; }
}
```

Now I know there is lots of articles explaining how to do this (I did google) but I do not want to use ajax, javascript, knockout or any scripts. Just plain MVC.

Hope somebody can assist as I am very new to MVC and json.

Comment: I don't think you can have MVC without JavaScript, and as far as I know the only sensible way to work with JSON is to use AJAX. Knockout actually does MVVC, which is slightly different than MVC.

Comment: if you don't want to use javascript then there's not a lot of point using JSON. If you just want to use an MVC view then write a loop using razor that will directly translate the items in your model into rows in a HTML table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just plain ASP MVC then don't convert data from file to json. Load it to your statically typed model (Global class) and just pass it to view from controller, i.e.:

Controllers\DataController.cs:

```
public class DataController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@path);
        var model = ConvertDataToModelSomehow(data); //model variable type: Global 
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then you can make View and use your model - Views\Data\Index.cshtml:

```
@model Global //your model type passed to view

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Server name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model.servers) //if Global.servers will be collection
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td> //if element has Name property
        </tr>
    }        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[More info here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)